# Python Print List new line and tabbed

Tags: python, list

I have a list with a variable number of integers in it (dependent on user input).  I am wanting to print this list of values, each one on a new line and tabbed in.

My current code is:

```
print("List values are: ")
print(*test_list, sep = "\n\t")
```

The problem with this is that the first entry isn't tabbed in so the output is:

```
List values are: 
1
     2
     3
```

how do I ensure the first value tab's in as well?

Comment: Add it to the line before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sep` argument adds the new line and tab between the values of the list; that's why you are getting a behavior like this.

What you could do is add an `end` argument to the first print statement.

```
print("List values are: ",end="\n\t")
print(*test_list,sep = "\n\t")
```